# Auto-populating Infopath fields from a Sharepoint list after selecting a drop down

Tags: infopath, infopath-data-connections

I currently have two lists one titled **Book of Work** which holds details around on-going projects and the other titled **Book of Work Amendments** which are requests submitted by users to change project details (through an InfoPath form).

There is a column in the BoW Amendments list entitled ***Select Project*** which has a lookup to ***Project Name*** in the BoW list. The aim is that when a user chooses an option from the ***Select Project*** drop-down, other fields in the form such as ***Project Manager***, ***Project Description*** will be automatically populated with data from that row in the BoW table.

I have connected both SharePoint Lists as data connections with **BoW Amendments** being the primary and **BoW** the secondary. If we take the ***Project Manager*** field as an example the method I have attempted is as follows:

- Create a rule with condition **Select Project is not blank**
- Action - Set a field's value: **Field: Project Manager** (BoW
  Amendments - Primary) **Value: Project Manager** (BoW - Secondary)
  **Add Filter: Project_Name** (BoW - Secondary) **= Select Project** (BoW - Primary)

Currently this is not populating the field when the project is selected in the drop down, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your drop down causing a post back? Try forcing it to cause a post back in the options for the control.

Comment: In your drop-down list for the projects, is the actual value the ID or the project name? Make sure that the value being selected in the dropdown list matches whatever value you're filtering against. Lookup columns can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @Omegacron - You were correct, the actual value in the dropdown was the ID. I have re-set the formula to **filter: ID = Select Project**. It's still not working correctly, is there anything else that could be casuing the issue? For example should the condition be different, or does it matter whether I'm choosing query or data fields?

Comment: I've seen issues with both before - if query doesn't work, try matching the data one. An alternate method would be to create rules on the dropdown where the first step sets the query ID to your selection, second queries the data connection, third returns the data values. The downside to this method is that you have to reset your data connection again to get the full list elsewhere in the form.